# What is the best way to find an element in a regex expression in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of strings in R like so:

```
"A(123:456)"
"B(23456:345)"
"C(3451:45600)"
```

I want to parse out the first number and the second number in the parenthesis for all these items:

```
first   second
123     456
23456   345
3451    45600
```

What is the best way to do this in a vectorized manner? I've thought of using substrings and index of, but then heard of regexes, but am wondering of the most "R" way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `regexpr` to match the pattern,
and `regmatches` to extract the matched patterns.

You could define the pattern to match (to be extracted) as `\\d+`, which means 1 or more digits.
This will match the first 3 digits that occur in each pattern.
And extract the matches with `regmatches`, like this:

```
v <- c("A(123:456)", "B(234:345)", "C(345:456)")
regmatches(v, regexpr('\\d+', v))
```

The above will give a vector of values:

```
[1] "123" "234" "345"
```

To get a `data.frame` with two columns of the numeric values,
you can use `gregmatches` instead of `regmatches`.
That returns a list of lists,
from which you can extract the values into vectors:

```
m <- regmatches(v, gregexpr('\\d+', v))
first <- sapply(m, function(x) x[[1]])
second <- sapply(m, function(x) x[[2]])
```

Or as [@RuiBarradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas) pointed out in a comment, you can simplify the `sapply` calls like this:

```
first <- sapply(m, '[[', 1)
second <- sapply(m, '[[', 2)
```

Comment: @RichScriven OP changed the question after my answer :-/

Comment: I tried `gregexpr`, but it seems to get every digit.

Comment: @user3685285 The update to your question invalidated my answer. In the future, please don't make such edits. I updated my answer to handle your updated question, but let's not make this a habit. If you have further questions, post a new question, do not update this one.

Comment: Note that the two `sapply` can be simplified: `first <- sapply(m, '[[', 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with regex:

```
# Your data
df <- data.frame(obs=c("A(123:456)","B(234:345)","C(345:456)"))
# extraction:
df$first <- gsub(df$obs,pattern="^.*\\((.*)\\:.*$",replacement="\\1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.
The first is the simplest and if your strings *always* have exactly two characters followed by the three digit number of interest, it will work.
The second uses regular expressions.

```
substr(x, 3, 5)
[1] "123" "234" "345"

sub("^.*\\(([[:digit:]]*).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "123" "234" "345"
```

Then, if you want numeric results, use `as.integer` or `as.numeric`.

**DATA.**

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"A(123:456)"
"B(234:345)"
"C(345:456)"')
```

**EDIT.**
After the question's edit by the OP, the solutions above are no longer valid. The following one is. Note that the regex has changed and that I now also use `strsplit`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(sub("^.*\\((.*)\\).*$", "\\1", x), ":"))
res <- as.data.frame(res, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(res) <- c("first", "second")
res
#  first second
#1   123    456
#2   234    345
#3   345    456
```

The columns of this dataframe are both of class `character`. In order to have numbers, coerce them with

```
res[] <- lapply(res, as.integer)
```